# iOS Identify speakers using SIRI kit

Tags: ios, speech-to-text, sirikit

I implemented SIRI kit in app for speech to text and its working fine. It display text based on user speak.

Now I have requirement that Identify the speaker and based on the speaker display text in different color.

**Example:**

When user1 speaks => display text in Redcolor

When user2 speaks => display text in Greencolor

I referred [SIRI kit demo](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/).

Please help me or give your ideas that how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't. Siri performs speaker-independent language recognition, not speaker recognition

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for reply. Can you please tell me other solution for it. Like how can I achieve this without siri kit?

Comment: The speech recognition framework in iOS doesn't do speaker recognition. You would need to find another framework or service, but recommendations are off topic for SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recognizing multiple peoples voices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914148/recognizing-multiple-peoples-voices)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev How can I use that library in ios?